# Прозрачность в canvas сжимает картинку

Tags: javascript, canvas

Только знакомлюсь с `canvas` и хотел бы выяснить, как в нем реализовать обычный `opacity`. Потому что при использовании `globalAlpha` картинка сжимается, а не исчезает. Планируется сделать слайдер с `fade` эффектом и при пролистывании слайдов, создается неприятный эффект из-за некорректной работы `globalAlpha`. Как это можно исправить?

Наброски: https://jsfiddle.net/tqyod1xw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут пара вариантов, цвета меняются путем применения fillStyle

`ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 00, 0.5)";`

А так можно использовать `globalAlpha` или `globalCompositeOperation`

ссылка на вариант смены картинок [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/aXZqqq?editors=0010)

[globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)
[globalAlpha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha)

Comment: Можете подробнее?

Comment: Ну смотрите, вы можете заливать прозрачными слоями весь канвас, пока он не очистится, допустим 10 раз по 0,1 прозрачности в итоге он зальет все черным, или поменяйте 0 на 255, будет белый. Во втором варианте используя ctx.globalCompositeOperation="lighten" он как бы выпалит все.

Comment: А если мне нужно симетировать переливание одного изображения на другое? Реализовать эффект `fadeOut`, `globalAlpha` тут не помогает.

Comment: Добавил кодпен, со сменой картинок.

Comment: Благодарю за потраченное время, но я хотел бы выяснить как это реализовать именно с плавной сменой картинок. Где изображение накладывается на другое.

Comment: Так заливайте по очереди, одну на вторую

Comment: А если вам нужно с эфектом перехода одну в другую, тут нужно картинки разбивать на точки. Это уже сложнее.

Comment: Я вас понял. Дело в том что я и так заливаю одно изображение на другое, но так как одно нужно прятать, а другое отображать, я использую `globalAlpha`, который и сжимает изображение при исчезновении. Я так понимаю чтобы избежать данного эффекта мне нужен `canvas` на каждое изображение отдельно? И для `fade` эффекта, просто один `canvas` перекрывать другим, верно?

Comment: Зачем? Поправил кодпен.  Можно просто заливать не белым а картинкой.

Comment: Смотрите. В вашем примере все равно, одно изображение полностью исчезает, потом другое появляется (разница лишь в том, что есть бекграунд, из-за которого создается иллюзия `fade` эффекта). У меня стоит "острая" необходимость менять плавно одно изображение, на другое. Каждое изображение должно обрабатываться именно с помощью `canvas`.

Comment: Должен получится слайдер, в котором плавно меняются изображения в `canvas`.

Comment: Так рисуйте два одному прозрачность поднимайте второму опускайте.

Comment: Я так и сделал. При быстрой прокрутке видны пиксели.

Comment: Не могу понять не видя кода. А зачем вообще делать канвасом не проще просто стилями ?

Comment: Мне нужен канвас для изображений, поэтому приходится имитировать слайдер на канвасе.

Comment: Там все просто. Можете сами попробовать сделать fade эффект на канвасе, с возможностью ручного переключения. Будут видны пиксели, если быстро листать.

Comment: Подправил кодпен еще раз теперь два массива картинок и они меняются случайно одна в одну.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Я разобрался в чем у меня была проблема, решил все обходным путем. Ваш пример более-менее неплохой, поэтому отмечу его как ответ.